# Custom Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, custom-formatting

I need to format a certain column in excel such that:
Format is something like
**hel 02/03**
the cell must have three character string followed by space, followed by mm/dd.
How must my format look like?

Answer (score 0):

instead to use a format you can create a concatenate column whit a formula that combine the two column :

```
=concatenate(C3;" ";text(D3;"mm/gg"))
```

where C3 contains Hel and d3 02/03. If the value is in the same cell i have to see how is formatted now on your sheet to suggest a different use of this formula.

Comment: No I have to have this column to have this format. Concatenation is not an option.

Comment: And now what is the format of the column? Can you give and example..?

Comment: The column should contain a value like "abc 02/13"

Comment: Ignore the quotes. consider only the value inside

Comment: i undestand what you want but i not undestand actual situation, in this moment the what value do you have? how is formatted? for ex "abc02/13" or abc02-03?